# Sign in as a Google Group to create an Installable Trigger for App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

I have created a number of tools that use Installable Triggers to send emails.  Because I'm the one who wrote the scripts, and created the triggers, those emails are all sent from my account.

I am wondering if there is a way to create those installable triggers, not as my own account, but as a Google Group account.  Ideally, I would like for those triggered emails to be sent from the Group's account, as opposed to my own.  I am an Owner of the Google Group that I would like to use, so if it's possible, I should have the appropriate security.  I'm just not sure if there's a way to log in as the Group, so that I can create the triggers from the Group's account, and therefore have the emails sent from the Group's account.  Is that possible?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, was the answer below able to fix your issue?

Comment: Hello @NaziA; I'm still doing some testing on this, which is the only reason I haven't accepted the answer yet.  I suspect that this is going to solve my issues, yes.  But I haven't had a chance to really dig into the script side of it, now that I have been able to add the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sign in your group in the script, you just need to add the group email to your gmail settings [`Send mail as:`](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts)

[image: sample]

After adding it, a window will prompt you and add your group credentials there. After confirmation, you should be able to use that email as your parameter for `sendEmail`. See code below.

#### Code:

```
function sendEmailUsingGroupEmail() {
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var groupEmail = "group@domain.com";
  var toEmail = "test@domain.com";
  var strSubject = "subject";
  var strContent = "this is content";
  
  // Check first if that email exists after adding
  if(alias.includes(groupEmail))
    GmailApp.sendEmail(toEmail,strSubject,strContent,{from: groupEmail});
}
```

Comment: Hello @NaziA; it took me much longer to get back to working with this than I had expected.  But this definitely appears to have resolved my issue.  I am now able to send emails from the script, using a Group I am a member of as the Send From address.  Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem @Andrew, glad that you were still able to resolve it. Good luck.